# Recursively count directories and files with a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, recursion

I'm trying to write a shell script that will recursively count all the files and sub-directories in a directory and also all the hidden ones. My script can count them however it can't detect hidden files and directories that are in a sub-directory. How can i change it so that it is able to do this? Also i cannot use find, du or ls -R

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
dir=0
hiddendir=0
hiddenfiles=0
x=0
items=( $(ls -A) )
amount=( $(ls -1A | wc -l) )

counter() {
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
        let dir+=1
        if [[ "$i" == .* ]]; then
            let hiddendir+=1
            let dir-=1
        fi
        search "$i"
    elif [ -f "$i" ]; then
        let files+=1
        if [[ "$i" == .* ]]; then
            let files-=1
            let hiddenfiles+=1
        fi
    fi
}
search() {
    for i in $1/*; do
        counter "$i"
    done
}
while [ $x -lt $amount ]; do
    i=${items[$x]}
    counter "$i"
    let x+=1
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash -e

shopt -s globstar dotglob # now ** lists all entries recursively

cd "$1"

dir=0 files=0 hiddendir=0 hiddenfiles=0

counter() {
   if [ -f "$1" ]; then local typ=files
   elif [ -d "$1" ]; then local typ=dir
   else continue
   fi
   [[ "$(basename "$1")" == .* ]] && local hid=hidden || local hid=""
   ((++$hid$typ))
}

for i in **; do
   counter "$i"
done

echo $dir $files $hiddendir $hiddenfiles
```

Comment: Are you really using `expr` and `eval`? Do you really do that in real life, on a daily basis? With a `#!/bin/bash` shebang? Seriously?

Comment: `1.` [Yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760732/capture-output-of-error-in-bash-exec-i-o-redirection/27761084#27761084) `2.` `a)` Yes. `b)` No. `3.` Yes. `4.` Yes.

Comment: Thank you, however this does the opposite of what mine was doing. It can only see hidden files in the original directory, but if there is a hidden directory then surely all the subdirectories and files inside are also hidden?

Comment: I actually tried it. It counts visible directories, visible files, hidden directories and hidden files. A visible entry inside a hidden directory is counted as visible. For example, relative to $1, `.dir` is hidden, `.dir/dir` is visible, `.dir/.file` is hidden. They are all counted.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this:

```
find . | wc -l
```

Comment: That's short and elegant. Sam seems to be bound to this condition: `cannot use find, du or ls -R`. Unless Sam is allergic against these commands or bound by a religious vow, I guess it's some kind of homework Sam is supposed to do.