# Capture output of error in bash exec I/O redirection

Tags: bash, shell, tcp, io-redirection

I want to open a TCP socket in bash, using the `/dev/tcp/host/port` psuedo-[device syntax](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/devref1.html), but I need to recover gracefully if the `host/port` endpoint is not listening. This is easy if all I'm doing is sending data to the socket, or pulling data from it, since I can just use one-off redirection, i.e.:

```
echo 'ping' 2> >(logger) >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8080
```

Or, reading from the socket:

```
cat 2> >(logger) </dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8080
```

Where `logger` is the standard [logger](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger) that writes lines from stdin to syslog.

The problem is that in some cases I need to write a request to the socket and get a response back. So I need to open a file descriptor for the socket with [`exec`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), but in this case, capturing the "-bash: connect: Connection refused" error is harder, since I don't want to redirect all output in the shell, which is what `2> >(logger)` does when used in the context of exec. The following works great if the endpoint is down (since bash hits an error when opening the socket, and resets all redirections), but renders my shell pretty useless if it is able to make the connection.

```
exec 2> >(logger) 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8080
```

So far, the best solution I've come up with is the following, where I open a file descriptor (fd 9) pointing to the original STDERR, redirect STDERR (fd 2) to my logger, open the socket on fd 3, then set fd 2 back to the original STDERR, and close my temporary STDERR alias (fd 9).

```
exec 9>&2 2> >(logger) 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8080 2>&9 9>&-
```

Which seems like a lot of work for something so simple. Is there a way to tell bash that I want to redirect STDERR while bash runs the `exec` command, instead of considering the redirection as a literal argument to `exec`?

---

Please keep your answers / suggestions **limited to bash** (up to bash 4.3.30). I know about `telnet`, `netcat`, `socat`, etc. The idea for the [project](https://github.com/chbrown/ritual) I'm working on (where this bash issue came up) arose from frustration at how slow a particular [tool](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump) is, which is due to how it proxies all of its shell helpers off to external (python) interpreters. Also, I'd like to avoid `mkfifo` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
eval 'exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8080' 2> >(logger)
```

or, much better because it does not destroy the old file descriptor 3:

```
eval 'exec {fd}<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8080' 2> >(logger)
```

which uses the smallest free file descriptor and assigns it to fd.

```
unset fd
eval 'exec {fd}<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8080' 2> >(logger)

if test $? != 0 # status of the last command - 0 if the connection succeeded
then
   echo cannot open connection >&2
fi

# $? shows the last status only. Later you can check success this way:

if test -z "$fd"
then
   echo could not open connection >&2 # past tense because it's later now
else
   echo some data to transmit >&$fd
   IFS= read -r just_on_line_of_response <&$fd
fi
```

Once you are done, delete the connection using

```
exec {fd}>&-
```

This will work as well:

```
eval "exec $fd>&-"
```

But this fails miserably plus closes your stdout:

```
exec $fd>&-
```